# String[] Pointing to the same reference in VO object

Tags: java, reference, arrays

**Consider the following two classes** (one is a `Main` with `main()` method):

***The VO class:***

```
public class TheVO {
    private String[] theValues = null;
    /**
     * 
     */
    public TheVO(String[] theParam) {
        this.theValues = theParam;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String[] getValues(){
        return this.theValues;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
        if(this.theValues == null){
            return buf.toString();
        }
        for(String read:this.theValues){
            buf.append(read);
            buf.append(" ");
        }
        return buf.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

***The main class:***

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * 
     */
    public Main() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheVO theV = new TheVO(new String[]{"Hello","World!!"});
        String[] vale = theV.getValues();
        vale[0] = "Goodbye";
        System.out.println(theV);
    }
}
```

**Result after execution:**

Goodbye World!!

**Question:**

I know that the `vale` array variable is referring to the same variable parsed in the constructor and if I change one of the indexes in the array it changes the same `String[]` in the VO.

**How do I "fix" or change the TheVO class so that my result is?:**

Hello World!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the getValues(); method to return a copy of TheVO.theValues array instead of a reference to the original array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use defensive copying: copy the `String[]` in your constructor. This ensures that the parameter is not modified after it has been passed to your VO class. Then copy the `String[]` in the getter to avoid the caller of the getter modifying your internal `String[]`. The simplest way to copy an arrray is to call `clone`:

```
this.theValues = theParam.clone();
```

If you used collections instead of arrays you could get rid of the defensive copy in the getter by wrapping your collection using [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) instead (which is a much cheaper operation):

```
private List<String> theValues;

public List<String> getValues(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.theValues);
}
```

You will still need the defensive copy in the constructor, 'though.

Comment: I don't want to resort to using a list. Still want to return the string[].

Comment: Then you'll need to do the defensive copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate (or clone) your String[] in the getValues() method.

That way, by creating a new array, you lose the coupling between String arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to perform a copy of the internal array when returning from `TheVO.getValues()`. If you are running on Java 1.6, you can exploit the `Arrays.copyOf()` method.

```
public String[] getValues() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(theValues, theValues.length);
}
```

Note that there is no need to use `this` in order to access the instance field here.

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of the array in your VO Constructor

Comment: If you mean clone(). doesn't work. The instance variable is set to the clone and that clone is also set in the Main class. It seems like the only thing that works thus far is the clone() in the getValues() method.

Comment: No - not clone - System.arrayCopy() - can't remember the params of the top of my head, but it takes a copy of the source array, rather than just a copy of a reference to it.

Comment: `System.arraycopy()` is indeed the preferred/only pre-1.6 way of copying arrays. See the API documentation at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html for further details.

Answer (score 1):

change the getValues() method to clone the array...

Something like this...

```
public String[] getValues(){
    return this.theValues.clone();
}
```